# Create user account in phpMyadmin with PHP code

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7, php-5.3

I tried below code for creating a user account in phpmyadmin:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root');
    if(!$connection){
        echo 'MySQL Server Connection Issue';
    }
    else{
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "CREATE USER \'".$username."\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING \'***\'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'".$username."\'@\'%\' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `".$username."\\_%`.* TO \'".$username."\'@\'%\'";
        $mysqli_query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if($mysqli_query){
            echo 'done';
        }
        else{
            echo 'faild';
        }
    }
}
else{
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
      <form action="?page=create_user" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="username" required>
       <input type="password" name="password" required>
       <input type="submit" value="Create User">
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

t it's only echoing 'failed'. why?
Explanation:
When the visitor visits the web page, he gets an html form with two feilds(username and password) and one submit button. If visitor fill in the form and submit it, the code must create a phpmyadmin user account using username and password which is entered in the form. I've added a code which will echo 'faild' if the code have faild on creating MySQL user. It's now showing the 'faild' word when I tried submitting the form. It means that thee's somekind of error in the code. But I can't figure it out. Please help me on this....

Comment: Replace `\'` with `'` in your SQL query as you don't need to escape single quotes inside of double-quoted string. Also it would be useful to display mysqli error message `echo mysqli_error($connection);`.

Comment: And also: your code is open to SQL injection attacks. You'd better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You need to learn the difference between PHP, PHPMyAdmin, and MySQL

Comment: I'm impressed you're running a server that has TWO versions of PHP ;)

Answer (score 0):

You were using backslashes not every single quote. Try this query:

```
$sql = "CREATE USER '" .$username. "' @ '%' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '***'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '".$username." '@' % ' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `".$username."' _%`.* TO '".$username."'@'%'";
```

Comment: I didn't found any part on the SQL query, which sets the password. Is it the problem??

Comment: Do i need to upload any web based application for making MySQL users through it?